# 8086 multiplying / dividing fractional numbers

Tags: assembly, division, multiplication, x86-16

I have to implememt a multiplication between two numbers with integer and fractional part. I tryed multiple strategy but i didn't find a working way yet. Can you please help me?

In my specific case:

first operand is a 16 bit var with 8 integer and 8 fractional

second operand is an 8 bit all fractional number, assuming it's 0.xxxx

I would like to find a way to use it with any kind of numnber and maybe also when i have div operations.

Basic 8086, with AX, BX.. No EAX ecc

Thank you very much!

Comment: That's practically a single `MUL` instruction ... what have you tried, what inputs did you use and what output did you get.

Comment: I think I made a whole load of stupid stuff... That fractional part was getting me mindblown.. I tried to shift and multiply any single bit for a constant and sum them all...  I clearly made a huge mistake...

Answer (score 3):

`IMUL` with a word operand multiplies two signed 16-bit integers (and `MUL` two unsigned integers) and produces a 32-bit result — specifically it results in:

```
(DX AX) = AX * operand
```

So use that and shift the result right by 8 bits to undo the effect of treating a fixed point scheme as though it were integral.

Comment: Is that so simple? I was getting mind blown by the fact of that 8 fractional bits. Shouldn't I create some specific algorightm ti manage it? Just a shit?


In this case: 
[code]AH <- integer part
AL <- fractional part
BH <- 0
BL <- fractional part 

MUL BX 
[/code]
And then I will just find my integer part in DL and my fractional part in AH (with DH full of 0s and AL with non-important fractional part?)

Comment: Yes, it's that simple :)

Comment: Yes, just think about the fraction. The CPU is multiplying the original number by n. But you know that n isn't really n, it's to be interpreted as n/256 — e.g. if n is 3 then that means you've stored the number 3/256ths. If n is 256 then you've stored the number 256/256 = 1. Since the CPU multiplies by n but you really wanted to multiply by n/256 the fix is to divide by 256 for yourself after the multiplication is finished. Which is just a bit shift.